# Odd Characters in Log File

Tags: cron, logs, null

I checked my cron log files today for a script that I have scheduled and the saw the following errors/characters:

```
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\
```

It goes on like this for many more lines...

I should also mention that my script stopped running entirely when these odd characters appeared.

What happened?

Comment: This can happen if one process has the file open for writing while another process truncates the file. The first process still writes to the position where the last write ended, the missing bytes are filled with zeroes.

Comment: A related question is https://askubuntu.com/questions/356981/ .